# Run Spring Boot application as non-root user on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, non-root-user, privileges, application

I have a Spring Boot application that I would like to run as a non-root user on Ubuntu 18.04. Currently it is running as root, and everything runs fine, but this is not best practice and could lead to security issues.

I have created a non-root user and have tried starting the application under that user. However, non-privileged users cannot run applications that use low ports, in my case 80 and 443.

What would be the best way to set this up in order to allow my new unprivileged user to run the application?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this one:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145512/allow-non-root-unmodifiable-sofware-to-bind-to-ports-80-443?rq=1